# Are the Founders telepathic with solids?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-ds9, telepathy

In the DS9 episode "Things Past" Odo creates a telepathic link with his fellow officers, a link that Dr. Bashir compares to the Great Link formed by the Founders because Odo's humanoid brain still contains traces of morphogenic enzymes. If these morphogenic enzymes were responsible for creating a telepathic link with other humanoids, is it possible that the same morphogenic enzymes in the Founders can create a link with solids?

Comment: As interesting as I think this question is, I doubt there's any canon answer. In that case, any answer must be primarily opinion-based. I'm voting to close for that reason, but if there really is a canon answer I'll cheerfully withdraw that vote.

Comment: I agree. To the best of my knowledge there's no other canon instance of a changeling forming a telepathic connection with a solid other than this, which makes any answer mere conjecture.

Comment: Though a possible canon answer might be: _"They are, if they are."_. As the female changling points out at Odo's first visit to the founders' world, when you become a stone, you _are_ a stone, and you understand what it is like being a stone. Similarly, to paraphrase Sisko, if Odo transforms into a duranium wall, all the scanners will pick up is a duranium wall. Which means that _any_ founder could trivially transform into a betazoid, _becoming_ a betazoid, and _understand_ how a betazoid brain does telepathy.

Comment: @Damon There are limits to "gain the abilities of what you transform into".  Odo could not manage the "understanding" part for a long time, and [Laas](http://en.memory-alpha.org/wiki/Laas) did not trigger the fire suppression systems that time he surprised Odo...

Comment: @Izkata: True, though Laas did transform to mist and fire (despite not triggering the alarm system, for whatever reason). Laas also manages to fly straight through space without freezing even though Odo demonstrates freezing (and states that they will die from cold) in the episode where he has that malfunctioning Veyoun aboard. Apparently, the span between what they can do and can't do is quite broad (including living and regenerating body mass without eating, breathing, or another comparable uptake of matter or energy).

Comment: Odo also can't resist mild, diffuse phaser exposure as demonstrated in starfleet HQ and can be killed by a single shot from a bajoran gun (mirror universe), though on the other hand, both he and the female changeling easily withstand concentrated phaser fire at maximum intensity (such as in that cave in the badlands or in the episode where Odo goes sleepwalking/stalking Doctor Whatshisname-from-Bajor). So basically, they can be, can do pretty much everything, depending on how the episode's author feels like.

Comment: I find @Damon's comments here really interesting, but I suspect that these instances are more due to shoddy writing than anything else. Changelings clearly have some limitations; it wouldn't be possible to design a virus to kill them if they didn't. What those limits are has never been adequately explored. It's entirely possible that even the Founders don't know them; Laas seems to have progressed far beyond what the Founders are shown to be capable of.